# Can Aquaman's trident cut through Superman's flesh?

Tags: dc, superman, aquaman

Zack Snyder sort of [*intervened* in a radio show](http://io9.com/zack-snyder-calls-into-local-radio-show-to-defend-the-h-1618361564) stating the following:

> [...] The cool thing is, with Aquaman his trident (people don't realize this) that could cut the flesh of Superman, if they come in contact. That's a thing that's in the canon. He's super strong. [...]

Is this true? And if so, how come?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's a magical weapon. Superman has no defence against magic.

http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Trident_of_Neptune

Here he expresses caution of magic, and then gets cut by magic teeth!

[image: superman admits magic makes him anxious]
[image: superman cut by teeth?]
[image: not just any teeth, witch teeth!]

Comment: You may wish to edit this down to just the important panels.

Comment: Or even elaborate a little bit more.

Comment: In the first panel note what Cyborg says to Superman : "I'm anxious. Always am around magic. If you're not you should be" and that's in reference to his vulnerability to magic.

Comment: i cut down the pages to just the relevant panels, i don't think this alters the content of this answer.

Answer (score 12):

The closest Aquaman seems to have gotten to stabbing someone with Superman-*like* abilities is in [Justice League #6](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Justice_League_Vol_2_6) where he uses his adamantine trident (the [Trident of Neptune](http://aquaman.wikia.com/wiki/Trident_of_Neptune)) to poke Darkseid in the eye and chest.

Darkseid is regularly shown to have a similar level of durability to Superman so he's a pretty reasonable analogue in terms of sheer physical resistance.

[image]

Superman is known to be [especially vulnerable](http://www.comicvine.com/superman-sacrifice/4045-56220/) to magic weapons, especially when that magic relates to the "[essence](http://www.comicvine.com/wonder-womans-tiara/4055-51489/)" of one of the Gods:

[image]

Comment: Adamantine not adamantium. Adamantine is not an element, it's a term used to describe a hard substance. Adamantium on the other hand does not exist in the DC universe, it's a metal alloy made of steel and the fictional metal vibranium.

Comment: @Nullbreaker - I've updated it, but don't forget that you can make edits to another user's posts if you see an inaccuracy.

Comment: I didn't know! Noted.

Comment: Actually it's formed from Iron and vibranium not steel and vibranium. http://marvel.wikia.com/Adamantium

Comment: Superman is not "especially" vulnerable to magic. Magic just effects him as it would a normal person. ie. A magic sword doesn't cut Superman worse than a normal sword against a normal person... It cuts him as bad as a normal sword would a normal person.

Comment: @Durakken - Except that magical weapons seem to dramatically impede his super-healing powers as well.

Comment: @Nullbreaker adamantium doesn't need vibranium "proto-adamantium" used steel+vibranium, but later variants did not use vibranium

Answer (score 5):

In *Justice League: Throne of Atlantis*, Ocean Master is able to hurt Superman with the Trident.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if this would actually happen, considering the fact that the only thing that can hurt superman physically is a kryptonite spear. Basically saying, if the trident came in contact with his skin, it would have the same affect as any other metal.

Comment: Except that the trident isn't any metal thingy...